# dropdown menu disappear when behind has links in IE

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

im using SimpleJqueryDropdown menu..

im testing on IE7 and 8. when i mouseover the dropdown menu over hyperlinks, it disappears.
i tried z-index and it doesnt work in IE..

anyone has this problem b4??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem before. Fixed it using this jquery snippet. The snippet below fixed my problem in [this site](http://www.nyelpc.com/).

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // lower the z-index to negative to fix the overlapping drop-down menu problem
  // for IE browsers only
  // the check for support of leading white space should give us false for IE 6-8
  if(!jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace){
    $('.post-header').css('z-index', -2);
    $('.container').css('z-index', -2);
  }
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```